# Sql query to insert time zone in mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there any query to insert country name and its time zone in GMT, for a mysql database. I want to add all the country name and its time zone difference with GMT or UTC

Comment: I'm sure there is a CSV file somewhere that you can just load but what about countries which span multiple timezones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to google the list but you may have to actually write extraction code
On top of that, large countries like USA, Canada & Russia have multiple time zones
Its all up to you how you want to design the database and code according to that.

This is the list Fedora is using... 
http://unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/supplemental/windowsZones.xml

start from here

Here is another list

http://www.timegenie.com/world.time